# How can I get pip3 to find my root certificate in macOS?

Tags: command-line, certificate

I am trying to use `pip3` to install `matplotlib`.  My company's root certificate is at `~/Documents/the-certificate-name.cer`.  The output is:

```
myprompt % pip3 install matplotlib
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: ~/Documents/the-certificate-name.cer

WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
myprompt %
```

My current OS version is macOS Monterey 12.6.3.

Comment: You could try running with `sudo`, that fixed similar problems.

Comment: `sudo` didn't work.  I installed anaconda and now I guess I can live without pip.

Comment: @Rich006 The ~ is a shell construct. Go back to wherever you configured that certificate path to be used and put in the actual path name rather than the shortcut.

Comment: @MarcWilson That worked.  Anaconda was having the same problem as pip.  Replacing ~ with /Users/myuserid in .zshenv solved it.